# Simple Transfer of Files Over WiFi in Ubuntu (Python Method)

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, python, transfer

On Ubuntu 18.04 it seems I can transfer files over WiFi to any other mobile device or computer with a simple Python routine:

```
1. Open terminal
2. move to the folder I want
3. python -m SimpleHTTPServer
4. ifconfig (for inet ip)
5. Browse http://[myip]:8000/ from another device
6. Download files I want
```

Great. Now, how do I stop the Python server from serving once I've downloaded the files I want. How do I stop the darn thing? I don't want to continuously broadcast this directory to anybody within earshot of my router. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just able to press Control-C to kill the process. You aren't running it in the background, so that should terminate it right then and there.

Alternatively, you could just use pkill to terminate the process. pkill lets you "signal processes based on name and other attributes", so you would be able to simply:

```
pkill -f SimpleHTTPServer
```

to kill the process.

Comment: `Ctrl-C` won't work over SSH, right? So I'd have to use the `pkill` method?

Comment: Ctrl-C most certainly does work over SSH. Simplest way to test that would be to open a `top` session and Ctrl-C out of that.

The `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` command doesn't execute and continue running in the background - by default, it runs in the foreground and lets you see things like resources access and http response codes, so I'm not sure how you are executing the ifconfig command (unless you are opening a second SSH session or using something like tmux). If you are using multiple windows or panes, you should just go to the server one and Ctrl-C out of it. Or close that terminal. :)